# Can anybody tell me why I get a file listing error on a NAS drive when using GetFiles in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, getfiles

I suspect that I am making a weird mistake here but searched for hours and can't seem to find a solution:
I am storing AOMEI Backupper disk files from various PC's onto a NAS. To avoid the accumulation of files on the NAS, I have written an application in VB.NET to sort files and delete older sets.
I map the NAS drive on a local pc, say, as `Y:\Backups\PC1` etc... and although the application works perfectly well on networked pc's, it throws an `'Unable to locate part of the path'` kind of error when it gets to the `IO.Directory.GetFile(sPath,"*.adi")` part of the code as shown below where `sPath` is 'for instance) `Y:\Backups\PC1:`

```
Dim files as string() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(sPath, "*.adi", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Googling for some time, I have seen many issues like this but no real useful answer.

Any idea/help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers from Paris, France and stay healthy!

Philippe

Comment: try the full UNC path and not the mapped drive letter, e.g. `\\mynas.domain\Backups\PC1`

Comment: Thx for the reply. Will try this out asap but had’t tried this before since many posts I read were only referring to mapped drive letters. Cheers